# Custom Login Function with CakePHP's Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication, components, cakephp-1.3

I need to know how to customize the login function that I am using with the Auth Component. Currently, it is blank and being handled automatically by the component. I need to add some conditions in it that which I want to execute before login happens.

Comment: What kind of conditions?

Comment: Look your previous theme for isAuthorized() - this is the proper way. :)

Comment: Can you specify what it is you are trying to do? What conditions you are trying to implement. It is a little difficult to know how to help without knowing what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: actually this was related to my other question where I found out that i can use Auth.userScope to add conditions to my login procedure, so this doesn't matter anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/simple-form-authentication-in-1-2-x-x) tutorial will help you.

Comment: thanks, thats a nice link but i guess its for cake 1.2, things are different in 1.3 it seems.

Comment: Things are not much different concerning Auth.

Answer (score 0):

I just read a tutorial about it, you will need to create a custom component, lets say MyAuth which extend Auth component to implement a custom login function. A little complicated.

Source (dead):
<s>http://www.milestree.com/php/custom-login-function-with-cakephp</s>